# Copying a slice of an OCaml Bigarray.Array1 to Bytes

Tags: ocaml

I have an OCaml `Bigarray.Array1` mmaped from a file with `char` elements and a C layout. I'm trying to extract slices of it to `Bytes.t`. For instance, get the content of the array from character 3 to character 10 into a `byte` variable of length 7.

Is there a better way than looping over the index and using Bytes.set ?

For instance

```
(* this feels inefficient *)
let slice array a b =
   let bytes = Bytes.create (b - a) in    
   for i = a to b-1 do
      Bytes.set bytes i (Bigarray.Array1.get array i)
   done ; bytes
```

I'm aware of `Bigarray.Array1.sub` but it doesn't really get me closer. The problem is that operations are polymorphic in the array type... is there any specialized, efficient operation for char arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a `Bytes.t`, you have to copy the values anyway I think. 
The most optimal you can get is probably the following :

```
let slice array a b =
  let sub = Bigarray.Array1.sub array a (b-a) in
  Bytes.init  (b - a)  (fun i -> Bigarray.Array1.unsafe_get sub i)
```

`Bytes.init` uses `unsafe_set`,  and `Bigarray.Array1.unsafe_get` is the fastest way to read the data (and the boundaries check is already done by `sub`).